# Database migration in Django project

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, migration

I am working on a django project. I have this database on my system which has 10,000 of data. I made the project and in settings added that postgres database. Then I did a migration using `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate` and I got all the tables linked to my django project. I found out through some resource that during migration only the tables are migrated the data isn't. But I need all the data for that database. Any leads on how I can do that?

PS: I am new to django, so excuse.

Comment: Do you mean you have an existing database which you want to use in your project?

Comment: yeah i have an existing database and I want to use it in my project..